# Cannot import cv2 library with OpenVino

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, computer-vision, openvino

I'm trying to do inference with OpenVino Model Optimizer as detailed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nmf-aHeRFq4).

The code I have so far runs without installing cv2, but I can't get any further because trying to import cv2 consistently throws an error. The code is:

```
import openvino
from openvino.inference_engine import IECore, IENetwork 
import cv2

ie = IECore()

net =  ie.read_network(model='saved_model.xml', weights='saved_model.bin')
```

This runs without

```
import cv2
```

However, anytime the cv2 import is included the following error is thrown:

```
File "/opt/intel/openvino_2021/python/python3.9/cv2/__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/opt/intel/openvino_2021/python/python3.9/cv2/__init__.py", line 112, in bootstrap
    import cv2
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/intel/openvino_2021.4.752/python/python3.9/cv2/python-3/cv2.so, 2): Symbol not found: _objc_alloc_init
  Referenced from: /opt/intel/openvino_2021.4.752/python/python3.9/cv2/python-3/../../../../opencv/lib/libopencv_videoio.4.5.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
 in /opt/intel/openvino_2021.4.752/python/python3.9/cv2/python-3/../../../../opencv/lib/libopencv_videoio.4.5.dylib
```

I've tried downgrading cv2 to various previous versions but this did not seem to help. cv2 is needed for the cv2.dnn.blobFromImage method which I'm trying to use in this script.

Has anyone seen this problem before? Not sure how to interpret this error message.

Comment: report the bug to OpenVINO.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Install and Configure Intel® Distribution of OpenVINO™ toolkit for macOS](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_macos.html#system-requirements), the Intel® Distribution of OpenVINO™ version 2021.4.2 is supported on macOS version 10.15 and Python version 3.6 – 3.8.

Please ensure your Operating System is macOS 10.15 and Python version within 3.6 to 3.8.